# The scroll bar does not work with pure parallax css

Tags: html, css

I created blocks with pure CSS parallax by following the tutorial:
http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites

My site is on Drupal 8 and Bootstrap 3. I managed to do the parallax effects in my block, but each block has a scrollbar.

My problem:
Each block has a scrollbar to make the parallax effect. I want to remove scrollbar blocks and use the scrollbar of my page to make parallax effect blocks.

Here is my site, the parallax effect is on the blocks of my homepage:
http://s1biose.com

Here is my style sheet :

```
.path-frontpage .main-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.path-frontpage .main-container .row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.path-frontpage .main-container .row .col-sm-12 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.path-frontpage .region-content {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.parallax1,
.parallax2,
.parallax3,
.parallax4,
.parallax5 {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-perspective: 1px;
    -moz-perspective: 1px;
    -ms-perspective: 1px;
    -o-perspective: 1px;
    perspective: 1px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin-x: 100%;
    -moz-perspective-origin-x: 100%;
    -ms-perspective-origin-x: 100%;
    -o-perspective-origin-x: 100%;
    perspective-origin-x: 100%;
}

.parallax__layer {
    height: 140%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin-x: 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin-x: 100%;
    -o-transform-origin-x: 100%;
    transform-origin-x: 100%;
}

.parallax__layer--back {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    -o-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

.parallax1 .parallax__layer--back {
    background-image: url("/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/images/parallax-1.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.parallax2 .parallax__layer--back {
    background-image: url("/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/images/parallax-2.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.parallax3 .parallax__layer--back  {
    background-image: url("/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/images/parallax-3.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.parallax4 .parallax__layer--back {
    background-image: url("/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/images/parallax-4.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.parallax5 .parallax__layer--back {
    background-image: url("/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/images/parallax-5.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

.parallax__layer--content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38823529411764707);
}

#block-section1,
#block-section2,
#block-section3,
#block-section4,
#block-section5 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #3b842d;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.parallax__layer--base h2,
#block-section1 h2,
#block-section2 h2,
#block-section3 h2,
#block-section4 h2,
#block-section5 h2 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.parallax__layer--base p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

#block-section1 p,
#block-section2 p,
#block-section3 p,
#block-section4 p,
#block-section5 p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Here is my html code (templates on drupal) :

```
<div class="{{ elements['#id'] }}">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back"></div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="parallax__layer--content">{{ content['body']['0']['#text'] | raw}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: s1bose.com is not reachable

Comment: @Varun Sukheja https://www.s1biose.com

Comment: updated in your question, it was wrongly mentioned

Answer (score 0):

open this link and just copy css after designing ur scrollbar and paste in ur project
[Try this](http://webkit-scroll-gen.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I applied your code but the parallax effect does not work.